# Make a navbar hidden until mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I am trying to have a navbar (within a div called nav-container) be hidden until the user hovers their mouse over it, in which case it slides out to present itself. The JQuery code I have written below does not seem to be working properly. Any help is much appreciated!

HTML Navbar Code:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav id = 'navbar'>

        <div class="link-container ">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">List a Coin</a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS Navbar Code:

```
.nav-container{
    width: 110px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: rgb(48, 162, 255);
    border: solid 2px none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
 }

.link-container {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.nav-link{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
var hovering = function(){
   $("nav").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
};

var leaving = function(){
   $("nav").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
};

$("#nav-container").hover(hovering, leaving);
```

Comment: have you tried 'slideToggle' instead of show

Comment: I added the CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple example. What's actually doing the job is:

```
#navbar { 
  transform: translateY(-100%); /* normal, hidden state */
}
...
.nav-container:hover #navbar {
  transform: translateY(0); /* when parent is hovered */
}
```

The rest are details. See it working:

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
#navbar a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar > * {
  padding: 1rem;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-container:hover #navbar {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav id = 'navbar'>

        <div class="link-container ">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">List a Coin</a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here's same technique on your example:

```css
.nav-container {
  width: 110px;
  height: 230px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: rgb(48, 162, 255);
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 10px));
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1) .2s;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-container:hover #navbar {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#navbar {
  position: relative;
}

.link-container {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

.link-container a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.link-container a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #ffffff21;
}

.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-container,
.nav-container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav id='navbar'>
    <div class="link-container ">
      <a href='#' class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div class="link-container">
      <a href='#' class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <a href='#' class="nav-link">List a Coin</a>
    </div>

    <div class="link-container">
      <a href='#' class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Took the liberty to leave a bit out, to advertise the presence of the menu.

Comment: I wanted the navbar to slide out from the left to right, kind of like its peaking out from the left when you hover. Is there a way to do this with this transform technique?

Comment: @AalokBorkar, of course there is. I updated the second example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mind if I use this code for my personal project?

Comment: ツ If I minded, I wouldn't have answered. I added it so you could inspect, tweak and learn from it. Take care and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

the menu is set to display none in the css and then jquery is used to toggle to block when hovered over

```js
$( ".nav-container" ).hover(function() {
    $( "#navbar" ).toggle("slide");
  });
```

```css
.nav-container{
    width: 110px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: rgb(48, 162, 255);
    border: solid 2px none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
 }

.link-container {
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.nav-link{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="nav-container">
<p style="text-align: center;">hover</p>
    <nav id = 'navbar'>

        <div class="link-container ">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">List a Coin</a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-container">
            <a href='#' class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough response, however, I wanted to hide the entire navbar including the container around it. I have added the 'display: none;' to the nav-container CSS, and replaced #nav with .nav-container in the JQuery code you provided. This does not work sadly. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: if the trigger is on 'nav-container' but 'nav-container' is display none than you can't hover over it as it doesn't exist on the page yet.

Comment: Your previous comment was extremely helpful as it made me understand the true meaning of display: none! So thank you for that. is there some way to make the navbar slide to the right on show?

Comment: updated answer, its not coming in from the side properly with this method though

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of maybe using the .animation() method, what do you think?

Comment: haha, i was thinking too complected. glad someone pointed out the overuse

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is to hide the navbar by default and then enable it only when the mouse hovers it.

You're code is fine, the only thing you need to add is a css statement:

```
nav {
    display: none;
}
```

Oterhwise `nav` is already going to be enabled by default which makes the jquery hover trigger useless.

Also it is good practise to use the jQuery ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var hovering = function(){
   $("nav").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
};

var leaving = function(){
   $("nav").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
};

$("#nav-container").hover(hovering, leaving);
});
```